# How would I graph this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I graph this: $t^2+3t=40$? I tried factoring $(t-5)(t+8)=0$ but I am not sure how to graph it because the function equals zero. I know how to do it if it is $y=t^2+3t-40$. I am probably overlooking the obvious, any help?

Thanks

Comment: Option 1: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bt%5E2+%2B+3t+%3D+40%7D, Option 2: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bt%5E2+%2B+3t+-+40+%3D+0%7D - See the difference?

Comment: @Amzoti So if I wanted to graph by hand, would I have something similar to option 1?

Comment: Yes, amWhy showed it. Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is an **equation**: you can think of its graph as the points where the function $f(t) = t^2 + 3t$ intersects the constant function $g(t) = 40$.

[image]

Alternatively, as you've factored it, we can put $f^*(t) = t^2 + 3t -40 = (t-5)(t+8)$ and $g^*(t) = 0$, and graph the points of intersection. These will be given by the zeros of the equation: at $t = 5$ and at $t = -8$.

Note that if you graph the factored equation, then the two functions graphed will be altered, but the points of intersection will remain, because the **solution** to the equation will remain unchanged.

**NOTE:** The only points that satisfy your equation are **two points**...points that happen to be the intersection of a parabola with a line: so indeed, do graph the parabola, and graph the line. But the key point here (excuse the pun) is that you need to highlight/identify the two points at which the **two** functions intersect.

Comment: I am slightly confused because my friend told me to use the vertex formula

Comment: Well, the equation you factored isn't a function $y = f^*(t)$. If we had $f^*(t) = y = t^2 + 3t -40 = (t-5)(t+8)$, then we would have a parabola, but the equation you've factored is an equation which is satisfied only at the points $t=5$ and $t = -8$. What you have is two points...that happen to be the intersection of a parabola with a line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vertex formular like your friend said to plot the vertex of $t^2+3t$, and graph the line $y=40$. Then the equation you got shows that the parabola intersects the line at 5 and $-8$, so just draw a curve connecting those two points and the vertex, and have it swoop up in either direction to get a parabola.